# Round integer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
start_time = time.time()
myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,
    '/html/body/app-root/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/app-home/div/div[1]/app-slider/div/ngx-siema/div/div/div[4]/ngx-siema-slide/div[1]')))
x = ("%s" % (time.time() - start_time))
roundE = float(x)
print(roundE)
```

when I print `Rounde` output is `0.016000032424926758` is there any way to get   `1 seconds ?` ?

Comment: Your `roundE` variable is float. Try to cast it to `int`

Comment: `print(round(roundE))`

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '

Comment: You are converting a `float` to `str` which isn't needed, just use `round(time.time() - start_time)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ceil()` function from the math library.

```
import math
roundE = math.ceil(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert your output to integer you just can use

```
int(roundE)
```

But in your case just converting to int is not solution.

```
roundE = 1  if roundE < 0.01  else int(roundE)
```

Or otherwise we need more info about your request.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly but if you want `0.016000032424926758`seconds to be rounded to `1` second, I would use : `print(ceil(roundE))`.

Make sure to import math, if not already done.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

a = datetime.now()

# Your codes to get data from selenium

b = datetime.now()

d = b - a # yields a timedelta object
d.seconds
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer? I was be flagged to deletion for low quality answer.